# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline tasks security

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible in Azure DevOps to create groups in such a way that one group has the ability to create / modify certain tasks within a release pipeline, while another group can change everything else about the pipeline (except those tasks created by the other group)?
I can group certain tasks in a 'TASK GROUP' and set security, but how do i create another group that can modify the pipeline without modifying the tasks within the TASKGROUP. If at the TASKGROUP security level I set the 'Build Administrators' permissions to 'Deny', and at the Pipeline Security level the I set the 'Build Administrators' permissions to its default values, would the Pipeline security override the TaskGroup Security? Or can i create another security group to deal with the task group(create/edit/delete) and set the permissions to Deny at the pipeline level for that new security group?

Answer (score 0):

> If at the TASKGROUP security level I set the 'Build Administrators'
> permissions to 'Deny'

I do not think that is recommended way to restrict Build Administrators to work with build/release assets. However, that is not restricted.

> would the Pipeline security override the TaskGroup Security?

No, TaskGroup Security does not inherit Pipeline security.

> Or can i create another security group to deal with the task group(create/edit/delete) and set the permissions to Deny at the
> pipeline level for that new security group?

That will be the more manageable approach. For this group, you may add `Allow Edit` for your task group and restrict editing on the all releases level.

Additinally, you may consider using deployments through yaml ([Deployment jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops)) and template ([Template types & usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops)).

> one group has the ability to create / modify certain tasks

You may create a template repository for these tasks and configure edit permissions only for that group: [Set Git repository permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/set-git-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops)